# Git: Equivalents to Codeline and Baseline

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently taking a Post Grad course and am tasked to create a Codeline/Baseline sort of structure with my versioning tool.

I have opted for Git and did some online reading.

To the best of my knowledge:

**Codeline**: A branch

**Baseline**: A bunch of branches merged together and labelled with a tag?

I really want to get this right.  Am I on the right track with my understanding? Thanks!

Comment: There's not really a concept of *"a bunch of branches"* in git. A branch is merely a temporary reference to a specific snapshot. Perhaps better would be *"a bunch of **commits** merged together and labelled with a tag"*

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following figure? Maybe your should search "git workflow" for some hints.

[image: Release branch]